# Java SwingWorker not working as expected

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I am writing a program where I match a name against a list.  If I do not get a match, I look the name up on an SQLite DB, extract name information into text fields and then display the card (cardlayout).  When I ran this, I only got the information for the last mismatch.  In researching this, I thought I could get around this using a SwingWorker.  I took my do-while and put it in a SwingWorker class and added a publish() where I wanted to display the information.  I get the same result, only the last mismatch is displaying.

Here are snippets of my code:

```
   public class processTeeTimes extends SwingWorker <Integer, String>
    {

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception
        {
       //   Process all tee times foursome at a time

            String memberGuest;                                     // Member or guest
            do                                                      // Process players in foursome
            {

                .
                .
                .


                    if (!firstOnGHIN())
                    {
                        System.out.print("No match - first (" + tsTime + "): ");
                        printGolfer();                      // Print no match
                        publish(golfer[0]);

                    }

                .
                .
                .

            }
            while (!EOF)


        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> golferList)
        {
            for (int gIndex = 0; gIndex < golferList.size(); gIndex++)
            {
                textFieldRMLast.setText(golferList.get(gIndex));
                cards.show(panelCont, ROSTERMAINT); // Show roster maint card
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void done()
        {
            .
            .
            .

            System.out.println("All done processing Tee Sheet");
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We can't compile nor run snippets, and we don't want the whole code base. Instead I strongly urge you to create and post a valid [mcve] -- please read the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get the same result, only the last mismatch is displaying.

Because that's what your code appears to be doing:

```
    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> golferList)
    {
        for (int gIndex = 0; gIndex < golferList.size(); gIndex++)
        {
            textFieldRMLast.setText(golferList.get(gIndex));
            cards.show(panelCont, ROSTERMAINT); // Show roster maint card
        }
    }
```

You're placing the data into a JTextField, and the minute more data is encountered, it immediately replaces the previous text with the new text. If you want multiple lines of data shown, then you should use a component that shows multiple lines of data, such as a JList or JTable.

If you want delay between viewing of data in the JTextField, then consider putting a `Thread.sleep(...)` in the do-while loop that is called in the `doInBackground()` method. Do not put a `Thread.sleep` in this for loop above, since the code above is called on the Swing event thread.

And note that if this answer does not answer your question, then yes, you'll want to create and post a valid [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: That was it.  Thank you.